# Class selector for a beginning of a game

Tags: python

Why wont it work.

Its a simple selection code that lets you select a character

import random

```
def Number():
    print ("1:Warrior")
    print ("2:Ninja")
    print ("3:Wizard")
    print ("4:Terrorist")
    print ("5:Sniper")
    print ()
    ClassNo = input("Pick you class:\n")
    return ClassNo

def Class(ClassNo):
    Class = ""
    if ClassNo == 1:
        Class = "Warrior"
        print ("you picked" ,Class)
    elif ClassNo == 2:
        Class = "Ninja"
        print ("you picked Ninja")
    elif ClassNo == 3:
        Class = "Wizard"
        print ("you picked" ,Class)
    elif ClassNo == 4:
        Class = "Terrorist"
        print ("you picked" ,Class)
    elif ClassNo == 5:
        Class = "Sniper"
        print ("you picked" ,Class)
    return Class

Number()
Class(ClassNo)
print (Class)
```

It keeps saying that ClassNo inst defined but then when I define it is come up with and error
plz help

Comment: It is a really bad idea to reuse built in names like 'class' for variable and function names.

Answer (score 2):

You need to catch the return value of the `Number` function, ie:

```
classNo = Number();
playerClass = Class(classNo)
print playerClass
```

A few other pointers. By convention, we use lower_case or camelCase for variable and function names and we use Capital letters for Class names. Also, if you're using a lot of `elif` in a row you probably want a dictionary. Here is an example:

```
possibleClasses = {1:"Warrior",
                   2:"Ninja",
                   3:"Wizard",
                   4:"Terrorist",
                   5:"Sniper"}

def pickClass():
    for number, playerClass in possibleClasses.items():
        print number, ":", playerClass
    classNo = raw_input("Pick you class:\n")
    classNo = int(classNo)
    return classNo

playerClass = pickClass()
className = possibleClasses[playerClass]
print className
```

Answer (score 0):

My first comment here, Im also pretty noob at python but I believe that the only input you have is within a single function, therefore that input is discarded when you get out of that function.

You should prompt for the class input outside of the function so it can be used globally in your code.

If I am wrong, I'd be happy for someone to whack me over the head...